# Frobenius norm identity

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading a book where they say mention that for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $T$ being upper triangular the following identity for the Frobenius norm hold:

\begin{align*}
|| A-T ||^{2}_{F}=\sum_{i > j} |A_{ij}|^{2} + \sum_{i} |A_{ii} - T_{ii}|^{2} + \sum_{i < j} |A_{ij} - T_{ij}|^2
\end{align*}

I tried to write out $|| A-T ||^{2}_{F}$ myself and I end up with

\begin{align*}
||A||^{2}_{F} - tr(A^{*}T) - tr(T^{*} A) - ||T||^{2}_{F} &= ||A||^{2}_{F} - 2 tr(A^{*}T) - ||T||^{2}_{F}
= \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |A_{ij}|^{2} + 2 \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |A_{ij}^{*} T_{ij}|^2 - \sum^{n}_{i,j=1} |A_{ij}|^{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no distribution involved, only the localization where the entries of $T$ are zero.

- $i>j$ - below the diagonal, $T_{ij}=0$
- $i=j$ - on the diagonal,
- $i<j$ - above the diagonal.

Remember that the Frobenius norm is the Euclidean norm for matrices.
$$
\|A-T\|_F^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n|A_{ij}-T_{ij}|^2=
\left(\sum_{i>j}+\sum_{i=j}+\sum_{i<j}\right)|A_{ij}-T_{ij}|^2
$$

Comment: I am well aware of matrix notation. I was just a bit confused about how the book obtained their identity, since I don't come up with that identity myself, when I write out  $||A-T||^{2}_{F}$

Comment: But do you see now how the 3 parts were obtained and that essentially no computation took place?

Comment: hmm well not really, but I can convince myself by plugging in for small matrices. Well in some sense the trace is just adding up the diagonal of the product transposed multiplied by the product, so it is probably from there somehow

Comment: see answer update